# Visual Studio - Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\[file].exe" because it was not found

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So, I'm trying to build a project I just installed Visual Studio to build this specific project (it is in vb6 so I needed to use the Visual Basic tools extension because i had Visual Studio 2015 installed). I have no programming knowledge on this area, only web.

And when I try to build it it gives me this error:

> **------ Build started: Project: Proyecto1, Configuration: Debug x86 ------**
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3812,5):
>   error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\Proyecto1.exe"
>   because it was not found. Done building project "Proyecto1.vb6proj" --
>   FAILED.
>
> **Build FAILED.**

Then I click on the error and it send me to that piece of code

```
<!-- Copy the build product (.dll or .exe). -->

<Copy
SourceFiles="@(IntermediateAssembly)"
DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)"
SkipUnchangedFiles="$(SkipCopyUnchangedFiles)"
OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"
Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"
UseHardlinksIfPossible="$(CreateHardLinksForCopyFilesToOutputDirectoryIfPossible)"
Condition="'$(CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory)' == 'true' and '$(SkipCopyBuildProduct)' != 'true'">

  <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="MainAssembly"/>
  <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWrites"/>

</Copy>

<Message Importance="High" Text="$(MSBuildProjectName) -&gt; @(MainAssembly->'%(FullPath)')" Condition="'$(CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory)' == 'true' and '$(SkipCopyBuildProduct)'!='true'" />
```

I already saw the existent questions for this problem and the solutions didn't worked for me.

Comment: Disable your anti-malware product and try again.  If it is Avast then plan to get rid of it asap.

Comment: @Davide I am also facing the same issue. Has this issue fixed ? If yes then can you tell me the solution for the same. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was like @Hans says it was my Antivirus fault (Avast) I disabled it to test if that was the problem, deleted the bin and debug folders and re-opened the solution and it worked perfectly.

P.D. Remember to add you solution folder to your antivirus exclusions.