# Debugger Not Installed While Starting C# Console App in Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have freshly installed Visual Studio Community 2017. I have a simple console app that prints a message. When I click the Start button I get the message

> Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program
>
> The debugger is not properly installed. Run setup to install or repair the debugger.

If I click on Debug in the menu and Start Without Debugging, I see the output of the program, so build and run seem to be working. However, I guess the debugger is not installed and I'm not sure how to install it. I've done exhaustive Google searches and seen posts talking about running regsvr32 and repair, both of which have proved fruitless.

EDIT:

Installing VS2015 fixed the problem.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Visual Studio? As a last resort you might try what this guy [did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41671506/324260).

Comment: @David Bradford, one community member also met this issue before, he fixed this issue after he installed the VS2015. We didn't find the real reason, but I feel that it was related to some old libraries or packages which were also included in different VS versions like the old .NET Framework or others. If possible, you could test it, we also provide other suggestions: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a75214be-4720-4134-aca8-f26751ea18a1/community-vs-2017-on-windows10-64-bit-debugger-is-not-properly-installed?forum=vsdebug

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT: that's the solution? I am facing the same issue and not everyone may be able to access VS2015. Also, since VS2017 includes the toolset for VS2015, why do I need to install VS2015 at all? I know disk space is cheap, but that's no real reason to force me to put that stuff on my system.

Answer (score 0):

@David Bradford, long time after Novell isn't it? Anyway, after looking all over the place this is the best solution I found. You don't have to install VS2015 just follow the directions below. I tried this and it fixed the problem for me and another person I was working with.

[Link to the VS developer community that has various comments and the fix below](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26630/the-debugger-is-not-properly-installed-cannot-debu.html)

Added a solution by Andrey · Jun 23 at 06:01 PM
Best Solultion
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug

```
Solution for this problem for Visual Studio 2017 Community.
```

Clean folders: Delete all the files in the two folders
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug
Then run repair Visual Studio by clicking the menu (three lines stacked up) to the right of the Modify and Launch buttons.
P.S. This issue happen because dlls corrupted. Here is this case
shareimprove this answer

```
This seems to be a known issue and is under investigation by the VS 2017 team. More information here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26630/the-debugger-is-not-properly-installed-cannot-debu.html
```